# Using text_field in collection inside form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, textfield

I'm having a very difficult time figuring out why this text field is coming up blank.  According to all of the Ruby tutorials I've read it should have the question's text value inside of it (as the value attribute in html).

Here is my markup:

```
<%= form_tag :action => "create" do |f| %>
    <% @questions.each do |q| %>
        <span><%=q.text %></span> <!-- This was a test, it displays it properly -->
        <%= text_field :q, :text  %>  <!-- This is the problem line -->
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class Admin::QuestionsController < ApplicationController
# TODO: Validations

  def new
    @questions = Array.new
    question = Question.new :text => 'winner'
    @questions.push(question)
  end
...
```

And here is my model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :text
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.  The Span seems to properly be displaying the text, but the text_field won't display it inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line to

```
<%= text_field_tag 'field_id', q.text %>
```

Comment: Why can't I use a method form helper for this?  Q is an instance of Question class after all.  Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
<%= f.text_field :text, :value => q.to_s %>
```

or

```
<%= text_field_tag :text, q.to_s %>
```

Comment: Neither of these works.  The first one produces the following error:
    undefined method `text_field' for nil:NilClass
The second one produces text fields with the following inside:
    #<Question:0x3717a20>
Changing the second one to q.text.to_s works though.